# drive.files.get error 500 from one server

Tags: google-drive-api

We are having problems listening and getting files using Goole Drive SDK. The problem started today without any changes on our end. The same code runs fine on our local test-server, so it seems to be due to the IP of the server.

The exception is quite vague:

Backend Error [500]

Errors [

```
Message[Backend Error] Location[ - ] Reason[backendError] Domain[global]
```

]

Can it be an IP-ban due to quota? Although I would imagine a more informative error would have been returned if that was the case.